# The initial render of the useEffect is disturbing the values of the cryptos. What is the solution?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jsx

I want that the Input field acts as a search bar and shows me the typed cryptocurrencies but because of the initial render of the useEffect, the value of the cryptos is being set to undefined and because of this no crypto is being shown on the page. Please suggest any alternate way to implement this functionality and also How can I stop the useEffect to get render at the starting .

```
import { Card, Row, Col, Input, Typography } from 'antd'
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useGetCryptosQuery } from '../services/CryptoApi'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import millify from 'millify'
import { filter } from 'htmlparser2/node_modules/domutils'

const Cryptocurrencies = ( props ) => {
    const count = props.simplified ? 10 : 100;
    const { data: cryptoList, isFetching } = useGetCryptosQuery( count )
    const [cryptos, setCryptos] = useState( cryptoList?.data?.coins )
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState( '' )

    useEffect( () => {

        const filteredData = cryptoList?.data?.coins.filter( ( coin ) => { coin.name.toLowerCase().includes( searchTerm.toLowerCase() ) } )

        setCryptos( filteredData )
    }, [searchTerm, cryptoList] )

    console.log( cryptos )

    if ( isFetching ) {
        return "loading...";
    }



    return (
        <div>
            {
                <>
                    <div>
                        <Input placeholder="Search Cryptocurrency" onChange={( e ) => setSearchTerm( e.target.value )} className="" />
                    </div>
                    <Row gutter={[32, 32]} className="crypto-card-container">

                        {cryptos?.map( ( currency ) => {

                            return (
                                <Col xs={24} sm={12} lg={6} className="crypto-card" key={currency.id}>
                                    <Link to={`/ crypto / ${currency.id} `}>
                                        <Card
                                            title={`${currency.rank}.${currency.name} `}
                                            extra={<img className="crypto-image" src={currency.iconUrl} />}
                                            hoverable
                                        >
                                            <p>Price : ${millify( currency.price )}</p>
                                            <p>Market Cap : {millify( currency.marketCap )}</p>
                                            <p>Daily Change : {millify( currency.change )}%</p>
                                        </Card>
                                    </Link>
                                </Col>
                            )
                        } )}

                    </Row>
                </>
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default Cryptocurrencies
```

Comment: You don't appear to be setting the inputs value to `searchTerm` anywhere, which I would have expected, is that intentional?

Comment: I am setting the value of the search term as entered by the user because in the onChange for the input I am changing the state of the searchTerm

Answer (score 0):

Simply can add a conditional `if` statement to solve the issue.

Let's take a look at the `useEffect`, As you describe at the component did mount, the `searchTerm` is still an empty string. By adding a simple `if` statement to check the `seatchTerm` value, `filteredData` and `setCryptos` methods only works when `searchTerm` has a string with a minimum of one letter.

```
useEffect( () => {
  if(searchTerm.length > 0) {
    const filteredData = cryptoList?.data?.coins.filter((coin) => { coin.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())})
    setCryptos(filteredData)
  }
 }, [searchTerm, cryptoList] )
```